# How to get JIRA ticket status using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jira-rest-api

I tried

```
var ajaxUrl = 'https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/TICKET-207?fields=status';
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:ajaxUrl,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type : "GET",
            success: function(data){
                alert('Sucess data: ' + data);
                var resultdata = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log('resultdata22: ' + resultdata);
                alert('resultdata: ' + resultdata);

            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('alert error');
            }
       });
```

but failed

Refused to execute script from 'https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/TICKET-207?fields=status&callback=jQuery31104841491505141431_1496758817313&_=1496758817314' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Kindly suggest some way.
Thanks in adavance

Comment: You should check what data is being returned from the atlassian api. It might not be JSONP. You should try running your code with dataType: 'json' instead.

Comment: @reinierkors Now getting this error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ****/rest/api/2/issue/TICKET-207?fields=status. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: This is a security feature of web browsers called Same Origin Policy. You cannot make an AJAX call to a URL that is on a different domain than where the JavaScript was loaded from (ie. has the "same origin").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because you are missing authentification to use the jira rest api properly. There are 3 methods you can use to authenticate yourself to jira before making any rest queries: basic, cookie-based and OAuth.

You can find all the crunchy details on how to implement authentication correctly for json in the jira api documentation located here https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-basic-authentication

On my side i use c# + json to perform my queries. 
A basic authentication operation needs this header information for all my request to work properly.

```
string authToken = "username:password";

request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authToken));
```

in your case it would probably look a little bit like this to be test tested over https only ( security reasons)

here is a curl example

```
curl -D- -u yourusername:yourpassword -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/TICKET-207?fields=status
```

here is your javascript with added header

```
var ajaxUrl = 'https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/TICKET-207?fields=status';
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:ajaxUrl,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type : "GET",
            beforeSend: function (xhr){
               xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
            success: function(data){
                alert('Sucess data: ' + data);
                var resultdata = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log('resultdata22: ' + resultdata);
                alert('resultdata: ' + resultdata);

            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('alert error');
            }
       });


},
```

Comment: Thanks @legrandviking

I am new to this, kindly let me know how i can use this in code

curl -D- -u yourusername:yourpassword -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/TICKET-207?fields=status

Comment: i have added the complete solution in javascript, NJoy and happy coding !

Comment: refused to execute script, because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @legrandviking. With help of your code I got the way.

```
function getTicketStatus($ticketID) {
    $username = '******';
    $password = '******';
    $url = "https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/$ticketID?fields=status";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $issue_list = (curl_exec($curl));
    ////echo '$issue_list===' . $issue_list;
    $ticketData = json_decode($issue_list,true);
    $ticketStatus = $ticketData['fields']['status']['name'];
    ///return $ticketData['fields']['status']['name'];
    return $ticketStatus;
}   

if(isset($_GET['id'])&&!empty($_GET['id'])){
    $jiraID = $_GET['id'];
    echo getTicketStatus("$jiraID");    
}

var ticketID = jQuery(this).text();
jQuery(this).addClass(ticketID);

var ajaxUrl = 'jira.php?id=' + ticketID;
jQuery.ajax({
    url:ajaxUrl,
    type : "GET",
    success: function(data){
    alert('data: ' + data);
}});
```